# How to get UTF8 html using msxsl.exe in windows 10

Tags: html, c++, utf-8, windows-10, msxsl

I am using msxsl.exe to generate HTML file dynamically from an XML and XSL. I have written the code in C++ using CreateProcess API and calling msxsl.exe in that. Since the output was UTF8 in Windows 7, I created all associated files(like CSS and JavaScript) in same encoding. Everything was working fine. When I am running the same application in Windows 10 (LTSC), the JavaScript was not loaded as the HTML is now generated with UCS-2LE BOM encoding. I tried calling SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8) just before creating the process. This didn't solved my issue. How could I get the UTF8 output irrespective of the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML files accept JavaScript with same encoding as the HTML file itself. This is the default behavior. When using JavaScript with another encoding, the charset attribute of `<script>` tag can be used([HTML script charset Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_charset.asp)).

So adding charset attribute like shown below I could fix the type of JavaScript in all OS, irrespective of the HTML encoding.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="MyJavaScript.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" />
```

to the stylesheet passed to msxsl.exe